# ¿se puede hacer un login con html,css y javascript?

Tags: html, css

hoy he estado pensando si se puede hacer un login con HTML, CSS y JavaScript sin base de datos. Bueno el problema es cuando le doy a entrar sin rellenar nada aun así me deja entrar a la página. Aquí está el código (lleva a la pagina web que estoy haciendo pero no le hagan caso):

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-register {
  width: 400px;
  background: blueviolet;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: calibri;
  color: white;
}

.form-register h4 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.controls {
  width: 100px;
  background: blueviolet;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #1f53c5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-register a .form-register .botons {
  widht: 12px;
}
```

```html
<section class="form-register">

  <h4>Inicia Sesion</h4>

  <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correos" placeholder="CORREO">

  <input class="controls" type="password" name="contraseña" id="contraseñas" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">

  <a href="https://pepix-initial-page.jesuszadkiel.repl.co"><input class="botons" type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"></a>

</section>

<p>
  <div class="have-account">
</p>
¿no tienes una cuenta?
<a class="a-link-emphasis" href="https://registrar.jesuszadkiel.repl.co/">
            Registrar
          </a>
</div>

</section>
```

si quieren ayudarme a  hacer mi pagina web vayan aqui:

https://bit.ly/3D6M8ez

gracias. que se la pasen muy bien.

Comment: Intenta preguntar de otra forma, en realidad estas pidiendo que te hagan el trabajo y aqui ese tipo de preguntas no son muy bien recibidas, si tu pregunta es si se puede hacer, si se puede, si no es esa tu pregunta, trata de especificar que quieres lograr y que has intentado, no solo muestres el html si no tambien el js

Comment: Si no tienes una base de datos donde almacenar a los usuarios no tiene sentido hacer un formulario de registro, ya que la próxima vez que quieran acceder deberán volverse a registrar, ya que en ningún lugar están los datos de su cuenta guardados, por lo que es posible hacer un sistema de login y registro con javascript, pero para ello es necesario que utilices una base de datos

Answer (score -1):

Como dice el compañero R.Nuñez, si tu pregunta es si se puede hacer.

La respuesta es Si, puedes almacenar los datos con js en las cookies para que después puedas consultarlas para el login y así harías un inicio de sesion.

El asunto es que es innecesario pues solo en ese pc y ese navegador podras ingresar y una vez se borren las cookies ya no se podra hacer mas.

Mi consejo es, si lo haces como practica bien, pero trata de ir mas alla y hacerlo con base de datos.

Comment: Hola Juan, creo que esto queda mejor como un comentario que como respuesta a la pregunta, no crees?

Comment: @Arriel parece que Juan no tiene la reputación suficiente para hacer un comentario, creo que puedes hacer comentarios hasta la cantidad 50 de reputacion

Comment: Es cierto lo que dice David Flores, lo siento, pero no podia comentarlo por la reputacion :(

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, @DavidFloresGarcía. Juan... Bienvenido al sitio! :)